# Scepticism regarding the exponent of -2 in Coulombs law?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law, spacetime-dimensions, coulombs-law

So lately I was speculating why nature choose the number 2 in Coulomb's law like why not 2.$10^{100}$ trailing zeros and then 1 or anything else. I find 2 a bit arbitrary  the given explanation being the cancellation of 2 while applying Gauss law in 3d space. So my question is, is there any fundamental explanation for this fact like from QED or something like that?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/93/2451 and links therein.

Comment: yes there is, have you researched this on wikipedia for example?

Comment: Other related questions: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/64673/precision-of-coulombs-law https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/220250/the-maximum-distance-for-which-coulombs-law-has-been-verified