# If the photon were massive how do the electric and magnetic field change?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, mass, maxwell-equations

According to electrodynamics the photon is massless. That is due to gauge invariance. But if the photon were massive  what would be the change in the electric and magnetic field? Is the massive nature of the photon connected with magnetic monopole?

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64673/

Comment: The best general reference I've found on this topic is Goldhaber and Nieto, "Photon and Graviton Mass Limits," http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.1003 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Allowing photons to bear mass, the electric and magnetic fields of a steadily moving charge
>   are no longer perpendicular to each other, as anticipated from Biot-Savart law.  The electric and
>   magnetic fields of such a particle depend on the gauge potentials,
>   φ
>   and
>   ~
>   A
>   . The orthogonality relations
>   of the particle fields and the direction of motion depend on the mass of the photon. The non-relativistic
>   correction to the particle fields was found to be related to the Lorenz gauge condition. It is shown
>   that the existence of magnetic monopoles inside matter is inevitable when magnetic field is applied in a
>   conductor. Their existence is a manifestation of the massive nature of the photon inside matter. Neither
>   electric nor magnetic current is separately conserved for photons, but their sum is. Massive photons
>   are found to produce electric and magnetic fields. A force proportional to the square of the current is
>   found to act along the wire,
>   F=
>   1
>   2
>   μ
>   0
>   I
>   2
>   , where
>   μ
>   0
>   is vacuum permeability.

Citation from:

http://onlinewww.jpier.org/PIERM/pierm34/18.13111603.pdf