# What is the range of the validity of the Maxwell-Faraday equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, electromagnetic-induction, induction

Similar to the [question about the range of the validity of Coulomb's law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/126987/what-is-the-range-of-the-validity-of-coulombs-law), I am looking for references to literature that investigates the emirical bounds of the [Maxwell-Faraday equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Maxwell.E2.80.93Faraday_equation).

However, it seems more difficult to find sources than it is for Coulomb's law (where a good overview is e.g. provided in Jackson, section I.2). It might seem plausible that the laws are valid in the same range because electrodynamics is likely to break down as a whole but is there any evidence for that?

Comment: It's more generic than you're asking for, but you might be interested to read this wikipedia section I wrote into Maxwell's equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Maxwell%27s_equations&oldid=810499549#Limitations_of_the_Maxwell_equations_as_a_theory_of_electromagnetism

Comment: Great, I read it! The article on "non-classical light" you linked to was also interesting. One could add that charge can be created and destroyed in pairs in QED.

Comment: However, this does not yet really answer the question because I would need solid experimental bounds for the law.